# How to fix this issue “Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `title` is marked as required in `Tab`, but its value is `undefined`.”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, jsx

I've just started exploring React, I'm trying to add tabs in my react project and that's not working it doesn't show anything

The warning in the console started with the warning message :
[image]

I didn't understand why it shows this warning message. can someone help me to fix this issue?

***Tabs.js***

```js
import React from 'react';


class Tabs extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super (props)
      this.state = {
        selectedTab: 0
      }
    }
    
    selectTab = (index) => {
      this.setState({ selectedTab : index })
    }
    
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="tabs">
            <ul>
              {
                this.props.children.map((child,index) => {
                  let style = index == this.state.selectedTab ? 'is-active': ''
                  return (
                    <li className={style} key={index} onClick={() => this.selectTab(index)}>
                      <a>
                        {child.props.label}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  )
                })
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="tab-content">
            { this.props.children[this.state.selectedTab] }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
    class Tab extends React.Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Tabs;
```

**TabsContent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';

export class TabsContent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                   <section className="section">
                        <div className="app container">
                            
                            <h2 className="title">React Tabs</h2>
                
                            <Tabs>
                            <Tab label="Pictures">Pictures content</Tab>
                            <Tab label="Music">Music content</Tab>
                            <Tab label="Video">Video content</Tab>
                            <Tab label="Document">Document content</Tab>
                            </Tabs>
                
                        </div>
        </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TabsContent;
```

Comment: The traces in your error say the hierarchy is Navbar1 -> div -> body (???) -> header -> figure -> a -- there's none of that chain in the code you've pasted.

Comment: @AKX I just got the wrong picture the quest has been edited now

Comment: You basically just rewrote the question and the "evidence"...

Comment: @AKX yeah I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it is coming from the Bootstrap `Tab` component. You need to pass the `title` prop as it is mentioned as **required** in the react-bootstrap [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tab-props).

Comment: I mentioned as required   Tab.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
   
}
 but still the same msg warn

Comment: There are two **Tab** components.
One is made by you, and the one you are importing from react-bootstrap.
Your error is coming from the react-bootstrap component. So, you need to pass the title prop to this component like this:
<Tab title="Pictures">Pictures content</Tab>

Answer (score 1):

Add Fragments right after return. For more info  https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

````
           import React, { Component } from 'react'
           import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
           import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';
    
           export class TabsContent extends Component {
                render() {
             return (       
                     <>
                       <div>
                       <section className="section">
                            <div className="app container">
                                
                                <h2 className="title">React Tabs</h2>
                    
                                <Tabs>
                                <Tab label="Pictures">Pictures content</Tab>
                                <Tab label="Music">Music content</Tab>
                                <Tab label="Video">Video content</Tab>
                                <Tab label="Document">Document content</Tab>
                                </Tabs>
                    
                               </div>
                          </section>
                      </div>   
                    </>
              )
           }
             }
    
              export default TabsContent;
    ```
````